# Split line by polygon where polygons overlap ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I would like to split line features to according to boundaries of individual polygons within a layer.

Where a line crosses two polygons, I would like the line split into two lines

I would normally use the intersect tool to do this, but because my polygons overlap the intersect tool is splitting the line crossing two polygons into 4 lines, rather than 2.

I could re-merge the lines, but not sure if there is a common field I can use to do this?

[image]

Comment: Dissolve the intersect output using a combination of the input Line OBJECTID and the input Polygon OBJECTID?  If you include a screenshot of the input feature class attributes, it would be easier to be more specific.